# IncompatibleClassChangeError with .jar files

Tags: java, xml, oracle, stanford-nlp

For one of my projects I have to use both the Oracle XML Parser and Stanford Core NLP. I've tested them both on separate projects without any issues, but when I try to put them on the same project I always get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:383)
at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.SemanticHeadFinder.<clinit>(SemanticHeadFinder.java:270)
at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.PennTreebankLanguagePack.typedDependencyHeadFinder(PennTreebankLanguagePack.java:197)
at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreePrint.<init>(TreePrint.java:108)
at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreePrint.<init>(TreePrint.java:98)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:264)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:126)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:122)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:112)
at unica.cp49177.nlp.Main.main(Main.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method: java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(Lookup,String,MethodType,MethodType,MethodHandle,MethodType)CallSite/invokeStatic
at java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:753)
at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:870)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1032)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1264)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:381)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:842)
at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:867)
... 12 more
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

**Edit:** This is the code that gives the error.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws XMLParseException, SAXException, IOException {

    File file = new File(file_name);
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP();

}
```

The exception happens when I call the constructor for StanfordCoreNLP.

Comment: Post your code that causes the problem.

Comment: Edited. It's nothing particular, though, it's just the call to the constructor.

Comment: Problem solved. It was an Eclipse issue, after switching to NetBeans there was no problem anymore.